# Stop launching a binary from command line

Tags: c, linux

How to make an application to prevent itself from launching from the command line?

I have a binary which should be launched by a daemon; but when somebody tries to launch the binary from command line, I should error out stating "cannot be launched from command line".
Tried googling but in vain.

PS. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/449682/stop-launching-from-command-line
I wanted to check if there are better ways than those mentioned in the link..

Comment: Do you know the name of the daemon?  If so, you could have the process obtain its parent's PID, and use that to determine its name.  And then simply exit with an error if it's not what was expected.

Comment: Use established security APIs. They are written with blood.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, thats a better idea..but unfortunately, this binary can be exec-ed from various other running applications.. hence, this wont work for me..

Comment: I'd consider this an issues regarding the proper settings of access rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure there is a bullet proof answer (to how to prevent a program to be started from command line). You could consider

- testing with [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) that `STDIN_FILENO` (i.e. 0) is not a tty
- try to open `/dev/tty` (it should fail) see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)
- testing with [getsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsid.2.html) that your are not in the same session than your parent, or starting a new session with [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html)
- calling yourself [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)

And I am not sure that you always want to reject being started from a terminal. For debugging, you surely want to be able to be started from a terminal. I actually would just warn, not quit, if started from a terminal.

And you probably want to install your program outside of standard paths, maybe in some `libexec/` or `sbin/` directory.

See also [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)

Comment: Maybe `/dev/tty` is a better way, and you really want to warn, not fail.... (or at least provide an option for not failing)

Comment: actually i need to fail if it is launched from command line.. and so, this isatty check is sufficient for me.. u mean to say isatty validation might cause harm in some cases for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

For the record, testing with isatty(3) only works if you are writing that binary files yourself. The method would fail if you are trying to prevent people from starting a third-party binary files.

Generally speaking, to prevent people from starting the specific program(s) from command line, the *nix way is to `chown` the binary file(s) to be owned by the daemon that launches it, and also to be of owned by the group say `no_command_line`. Then `chmod 705 binary_executables`, and put all those people not allowed to run the binary_executables from command line in the group `no_command_line`.

HTH